# Protractor 5.1.1 doesn't work with Chrome 58

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, selenium-chromedriver, angularjs-e2e

Recently my chrome browser updated to `Version 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit)`. Therefore, my existing protractor test is not working with the current version of chrome.
The error message is

> Failed: unknown error: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'String' in false
>           (Session info: chrome=58.0.3029.96)
>           (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>         Command duration or timeout: 18 milliseconds
>         Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
>         System info: host: 'WIN-DA72NJNI5DP', ip: '172.16.230.61', os.name: 'Windows Server 2012 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
>         Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
>         Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233), userDataDir=C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir7512_11086}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=58.0.3029.96, platform=WIN8_1, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]

Even i have updated my chrome driver version to 2.28 and then 2.29. but it didn't work.
Here is the more information about my current  testing environment :

- chrome: 58.0.3029.81
- protractor: 5.1.1
- webdriver-manager: 12.0.4
- chrome driver: 2.29
- nodejs: 6.9.4

Comment: What OS are you on? I have this same problem (though different errors) on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine, but _not_ on my Mac. The only thing that worked for me is to revert to chrome v55, and chromedriver 2.25 (2.26 & 2.27 kinda work but have a bunch of issues).

Comment: Oh, after scrolling, I see you're on Windows NT. I've seen others report similar issues on Windows and Linux... seems to work fine on Mac. I've been struggling with this all week... _seems_ like a chromedriver issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `chromedriver` is *outdated*. You need [`chromedriver` 2.29](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) for Chrome versions 56-58.

Make sure you have the latest `webdriver-manager`:

```
npm install webdriver-manager
```

Ad then execute the update:

```
webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome 2.29
```

Worked for me.

Comment: @UpalRoy please correct me if I'm wrong - you tried to execute `webdriver-manager update` which resulted into everything being up to date, right?

Comment: yes, but when it was not working with version 2.29, i manually changed it to version 2.28 because i got suggestion for other forums to update manually to 2.28.

Comment: @UpalRoy interestingly, updating the `webdriver-manager` and then running the `update` command worked for me - I've got 2.29 installed. Does it install 2.29 for you too?

Answer (score 0):

Try to update chrome driver by using below commands ,

webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome=2.28

webdriver-manager start --versions.chrome=2.28

as you are using incompatible version of browser and driver